# Obtener el valor de un <tr> de una consulta al momento de seleccionarlo y mostrarlo en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero que, al momento de seleccionar una fila de mi consulta en la tablas, los datos se muestren en el `input`.

Este es el método que tengo, pero no entiendo en que está mal. No entiendo como obtener los datos con el `row` para mostrarlos en los `input`. Les agradecería su ayuda.

[image: Consulta con jquery, usando DataTable]

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {`

        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#tableIntalacionMed tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            } else {

                $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                var d = $('#tableIntalacionMed').row(this).data();

                console.log(d);
                $("#Desc").val(d.desc1);

                $("#Obse").val(d.obse1);
            }
        });
       
    });

});
```

HTML

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="form_MedInstalacion" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Tipos de Instalación de Medidor</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table class="table" id="example" name="example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Clave</th>
                                        <th>Descripción</th>
                                        <th>Observaciones</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var lst in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>@lst.ProtMed</td>
                                            <td>@lst.Descripcion</td>
                                            <td>@lst.Obs</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Clave</th>
                                        <th>Descripción</th>
                                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                                    </tr>

                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Clave</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Clave" name="Clave" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs info" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Información de registro de transacción'><i class='far fa-comment-dots'></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top:7px">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="Descripcion" name="Descripcion">Descripción</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Desc" name="Desc" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top:7px">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="Observaciones" name="Observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <textarea id="Obse" name="Obse" rows="4" class="form-control" disabled></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
                        <div class="col-2 offset-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-per" id="Agregar"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i> Agregar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-per" disabled="disabled" id="Modificar"><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i> Modificar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-per" id="Eliminar" data-tip="" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Eliminar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-per" id="Grabar" data-tip="" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Grabar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>

</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Content/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/Comercial/Scripts/Hidrometria/ClaseInstalacionMedidor.js"></script>
    <script>
```

Comment: Publicá por favor tu código HTML,sino es imposible saber a que hacen referencia esas líneas de JS.

Comment: Si disculpe, ya lo agregue

Comment: En tu código JS hacés referencia al ID `#tableIntalacionMed` pero en el HTML no veo ninguna tabla con ese ID, solo con `#example`. Es un error de como publicaste el ejemplo o falta información?

Comment: También vi eso, pero como no me sabia la sintaxis lo deje así, pero ya cambie el nombre en esa ubicación al id de la propia tabla, pero aun así no hace la función

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta para poner el código como lo tenés ahora? Por otro lado, qué es exactamente lo que querés que aparezca en el input?

Comment: Los datos de la consulta, dependiendo de que fila se seleccione, esos datos apareceran

Answer (score 0):

No funciona porque con `var d = $('#tableIntalacionMed').row(this).data();` estás buscando en una tabla que no existe para obtener la fila, de una fila ya seleccionada y `data` que no está especificada.

De acuerdo a como definiste la tabla `<table class="table" id="example">` vas a seleccionarla por su id (example), con `$('#example')`; si quieres que sea `$('#tableIntalacionMed')` entonces actualiza la etiqueta: `<table class="table" id="tableIntalacionMed">` y no es necesario el atributo *name*.

Cuando creas el evento clic `$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () ...`, se aplica por cada fila, por lo que `$(this)` hace referencia a esa fila y hay que buscar los datos en sus "hijos" con `$(this).children()`, que te va a devolver todas las celdas (td) pertenecientes a esa fila.

Finalmente obtienes el texto de cada celda para asignarlo a los campos del formulario; En la primera celda (td[0]) tienes la clave, en la segunda (td[1]), la descripción y, en la tercera (td[2]), las observaciones.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        // var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                // Deseleccionar
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                // Limpiar campos
                $('#Clave').val('');
                $('#Descripcion').val('');
                $('#Obse').val('');
            } else {
                // Remover clase de TR seleccionada, si es que hay
                $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                // Asignar clase seleccionada a TR actual
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                // Obtener TD's
                var tds = $(this).children();
                // Asignar campos
                $('#Clave').val($(tds[0]).text());
                $('#Descripcion').val($(tds[1]).text());
                $('#Obse').val($(tds[2]).text());
            }
        });
       
});
```

```css
.selected { background: #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="form_MedInstalacion" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Tipos de Instalación de Medidor</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table class="table" id="example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Clave</th>
                                        <th>Descripción</th>
                                        <th>Observaciones</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Clave 1</td>
                                            <td>Descripción 1</td>
                                            <td>Observaciones 1</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Clave 2</td>
                                            <td>Descripción 2</td>
                                            <td>Observaciones 2</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Clave 3</td>
                                            <td>Descripción 3</td>
                                            <td>Observaciones 3</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Clave</th>
                                        <th>Descripción</th>
                                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                                    </tr>

                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Clave</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Clave" name="Clave" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs info" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Información de registro de transacción'><i class='far fa-comment-dots'></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top:7px">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="Descripcion" name="Descripcion">Descripción</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Desc" name="Desc" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top:7px">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="Observaciones" name="Observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <textarea id="Obse" name="Obse" rows="4" class="form-control" disabled></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
                        <div class="col-2 offset-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-per" id="Agregar"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i> Agregar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-per" disabled="disabled" id="Modificar"><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i> Modificar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-per" id="Eliminar" data-tip="" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Eliminar</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-per" id="Grabar" data-tip="" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Grabar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```